# How to display only few columns of a table based on the data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the table below

```
Name partno.  sch_date    WO#   owed panels
aa   1234     08/22/2017  121   22    26
aa   1234     08/22/2017  222   22    27
aa   1234     08/22/2017  242   22    27
aa   1234     08/29/2017  152   20    24
aa   1234     08/29/2017  167   20    24
aa   1234     08/29/2017  202   20    26`
```

Is it possible to display the data in such way that when the number of panels is greater than owed, then i don't won't to dispaly the other partno. schedule on the same date(sch_date).

Expected Result

```
Name partno.  sch_date    WO#   owed panels
aa   1234     08/22/2017  121   22    26
aa   1234     08/29/2017  152   20    24
```

Comment: What if there is a conflict on the same partno? `CASE` is most likely the function you are looking for.

Comment: I don't understand, you say you don't want to see results where `panels` is greater than `owed` but your expected results both have more panels than owed?

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea how you're getting from the table to the expected results either. There is no row, for example, with owed=20 and panels=27, so where is that second line of the results coming from? You need to be a lot more clear about how you're getting that 'expected results' because it doesn't make any sense at all right now.

Comment: What's the criteria for choosing panel = 26 for 8/22 and not panel = 27? Both satisfy the rule you stated in question.

Comment: Sorry, If in the first line item itself has panels  greater than owed then only display that for the give sch_date @niksofteng

Comment: @Aaron what i meant was if the first value in the table has panels greater than owed then i only want to display that row for that give sch_date

Comment: What do you want to do if the first row doesn't have more panels than owed?

Comment: @Aaron then display that and move to the next one and if the next has more panels than owed then stop there and move to the next sch_date

Comment: How do you defined the order wihtin date and partnumber?  by Wo#?

Comment: @xQbert i am searching by part number

Comment: I see in a comment you want to keep records if owed > panels... if it's encountered first.... but what if it's not encountered first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross apply may help here.  (note you can see why I asked about order in my earlier comment as the ORDER of records in a table is not guaranteed!  we need to know in what you want the records evaluated!  Date isn't enough (unless it has a time compoent not displayed that is different!)

WORKING example on Rextester: http://rextester.com/CAUK18185

Many assumptions made:

- When owned is > panels you don't need to see the record.
- You want to see the the lowest WO# when owed is < panels and suppress all other records including ones where owed > panels.
- If there are no records for a date, name and partno that have owed < panels, you want to see no records.

If these assumptions are incorrect, please provide a better sample set and expected results to test these types of situations and explain what you want to have happen.

```
SELECT Distinct B.*
FROM tblName Z
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 A.* 
                      FROM tblName A 
                      WHERE A.owed < A.panels
                        and Z.Name = A.Name
                        and Z.[partno.] = a.[partno.]
                        and Z.sch_date = a.sch_date
                      ORDER by A.name, A.[partno.], A.sch_date, A.[wo#]) B
```

For each record in A run a query which returns the lowest wo# for a name, partno and sch_date when the owed < panels.

***UPDATED:***
I see in a comment you want to keep records if owed > panels... if it's encountered first.... but what if it's not encountered first?

http://rextester.com/NXS51018

```
--First we get all the records w/ a owed < panels per group and assign the earliest row (that having the lowest WO) a RN of 1.  then we return that set.
cte as (
Select A.*, row_number() over (Partition by Name, [partno.],  sch_date ORDER BY [WO#]) RN 
from tblName A 
where owed < panels)

Select * from cte where RN =1

UNION ALL
--We then union in the records where owed >=panels and their WO# < the wo# from the CTE.

SELECT Z.*, 0 as rn FROM tblName Z where owed >=panels
 and exists (Select * from cte 
             where Z.name = CTE.name 
               and Z.[partno.] = cte.[partno.] 
               and Z.sch_date = cte.sch_date
               and CTE.[WO#] > Z.[WO#])  --Now this line may not be needed, depending on if you want all or just some of the WO#'s when owed >=panels.
ORDER BY name, [partno.], Sch_date, [Wo#]
```

---

After last comment update:

```
cte as (
Select A.*, row_number() over (Partition by Name, [partno.],  sch_date ORDER BY [WO#]) RN 
from tblName A 
where owed < panels),

cte2 as (Select * from cte where RN =1
UNION ALL
SELECT Z.*, 0 as rn FROM tblName Z where owed >=panels
 and exists (Select * from cte 
             where Z.name = CTE.name 
               and Z.[partno.] = cte.[partno.] 
               and Z.sch_date = cte.sch_date
               and CTE.[WO#] > Z.[WO#]))

Select * into SOQ#45619304  from  CTE2;  --This line creates the table based on the 2nd cte results.

Select * from SOQ#45619304;
```

Comment: if in the first row the panels are less than owed then i want to display that and move to the next one. If in the second row the panels are greater than owed then i want to ignore the rest of the partno for that sch_date. Thanks alot tho, you have been a massive help

Comment: ok so even if owed >= panels on a higher WO#, you'd not need to see it once a owed < panels is encountered.  Then the 2nd query block above above should be working.

Comment: is possible to insert the data i get from this into a table?

Comment: Like this. http://rextester.com/VEU6697 Remove the last order by (one can't order in a subquery/view cte unless it's with a top or other requirements) make the query a 2nd cte and then use standard `select into tablename from tblSource`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
SELECT Name, partno., sch_date, WO#, owed, panels
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE panels < owed
UNION ALL
SELECT Name, partno., sch_date, MIN(WO#), owed, MIN(panels)
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE panels > owed
GROUP BY Name, partno., sch_date, owed
ORDER BY Name
```